# Почему Пайтон не считает сумму, а выводит по столбцу среднее значение?

Tags: python, pandas

Вопрос: Пользователи из каких стран совершили наибольшее количество успешных бронирований? Укажите 5 лучших.
`is canceled` - бронирование было отменено (1) или нет (0); не отмененное считается успешным

Мой код `pd.pivot_table(df,'Is Canceled','Country',aggfunc='sum')`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему. А то выглядит как бессмысленный набор символов.

Comment: @Глеб В вопросе всё ясно и понятно.

Comment: @rotabor, первый комментарий добавил S Nick, а ему виднее.

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю, что агрегатная функция должна быть count. Группировать нужно по стране и считать `'Is Canceled' == 0`. И ещё какой-нибудь `Top(5)` добавить.

```
res = pd.pivot_table(df.loc[df['Is Canceled']==0], values='Is Canceled'
        , index='Country', aggfunc='count')
    .sort_index(by='Is Canceled', ascending=False).head(5)
```

Comment: В целом логика верная, но ответа на вопрос *"Почему Пайтон не считает сумму, а выводит по столбцу среднее значение?"* она не даёт

Comment: @АлексейР Ща дадим. А так-то ответ уже есть - агрегатная функция не та.

Comment: А мне вот почему-то всё ещё непонятно, почему `aggfunc='sum'` даёт среднее, а не сумму

Comment: @АлексейР Мне тоже непонятно. И не факт, что даёт среднее. Это ещё нужно проверить.

Comment: @АлексейР Я не думаю, что автора интересует "Почему Пайтон не считает сумму, а выводит по столбцу среднее значение?" Скорее всего его интересует, как получить нужный результат.